# repeat string-inflection command

Tags: commands, string

I would like to repeat `M-x string-inflection-camelcase` on several words.
For example in:

```
foo_bar baz qux-quux quuz CORGE_GRAULT GARPLY
```

I place my cursor on `foo_bar` and then enter `M-x string-inflection-camelcase`, which changes `foo_bar` to `FooBar`. I can then move forward via `M-f` and `C-f` several times and press `C-x ESC ESC`, which brings up `Redo: (string-inflection-camelcase)`. I can then press `Enter` to change `CORGE_GRAULT` to `CorgeGrault`.

However, this key sequence is slow compared to the `C-x z` `z` commands used for a basic `repeat`.

How can I re-execute `string-inflection-camelcase` more efficiently after moving my cursor around?

Answer (score 1):

[Define a keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html#Basic-Keyboard-Macro) that includes the change command and the move to the beginning of the next word. Then repeat the macro as many times as you need.